# How can i set iis 7 to get access to the site with www?

Tags: web, iis-7, server, no-www

I tried to set up the site settings in order to access it with or without www with no success. I only can acces it without www. (http://mywebsite.com). The IIS 7 is running on a windows web server 2008. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a public site, you can use CNAME DNS record, see: [Click Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/181927/should-cname-be-used-for-subdomains)

Something like this:

```
mywebsite.com    - A Record - Production Server IP
www              - CNAME    - mywebsite.com
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  But where do i have to set that? the site is running under an iis7, and in a windows web server 2008 so, i do not have a "cpanel".